# Derived Morita equivalence of associative algebras

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories, derived-algebraic-geometry

An associative algebra $A$ is said to be Morita equivalent to another one $B$ if there is an equivalence $$\mathsf{Mod}_A\simeq \mathsf{Mod}_B$$ between its corresponding abelian categories of modules. Moreover, whenever $A$ and $B$ are commutative, they are Morita equivalent iff they are isomorphic. On the other hand, we say that $A$ is derived Morita equivalent to $B$ if there is an equivalence $$D(A)\simeq D(B)$$ between its triangulated derived categories.  My question is:

Q. If $A$ is commutative and derived Morita equivelent to $B$, is $A$ Morita equivalent to $B$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be true by https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9810134.pdf , theorem 2.7.

Comment: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-the-london-mathematical-society/article/dualizing-complexes-morita-equivalence-and-the-derived-picard-group-of-a-ring/E5B75BEB7DED0A2594407D3281928C62 for non-pdf version